# Accessing WAMP server from a different network

Tags: networking, wamp, wampserver

I was trying to setup WAMP server on my machine . Am able to access the localhost from the same PC or remotely from other devices in the same network .

However I would like to know how can I access it from a different network ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a different network

Comment: @RiggsFolly : Different network as in outside the home network

Comment: Can I just clarify something here, is your WAMPServer at home and you want to access it from your work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the port 80 forwarding on your router.  Forward port 80 of that particular machine/server to your router.  That server should have a permanent local IP like 192.168.1.*** or 192.168.2.***, etc whose port 80 is forwarded to the public IP of your router.  This provides access to your server/machine with the set IP from outside your network!

For router settings, open a browser, in the location bar, type http://192.168.1.1 or whatever your router manual says it to be.  You will need the default user/pass to login.

In order to have a permanent access to your home server with a domain, You need to get a permanent public IP for your network from your Internet service provider in order to assign a domain name to it.

Comment: The router is a company router and I guess I will have a very limited access to change ports on it for security reasons .... Is there an alternative way to it ?

Comment: I'm afraid no my friend. Assuming that you're behind your router NAT, there is no possibilities to do that without having access to your network's router.